# validate fail when pushing AFNetworking to private cocoapods podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking

I'm trying to add `AFNetworking` to the private cocoapods spec by following steps.

1. clone `AFNetworking` from github and push to private gitlab
2. modify `AFNetworking.podspec` file and change the `s.source` attribute to the private url
3. run `pod spec lint --verbose`, fail with

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> Testing with `xcodebuild`.   -> AFNetworking (3.2.1)
>
> - NOTE  | [AFNetworking/Serialization, AFNetworking/Security, AFNetworking/Reachability, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Using new
>   build system
> - NOTE  | [AFNetworking/Serialization, AFNetworking/Security, AFNetworking/Reachability, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Planning
>   build
> - NOTE  | [AFNetworking/Serialization, AFNetworking/Security, AFNetworking/Reachability, and more...] xcodebuild:  note:
>   Constructing build description
> - NOTE  | [AFNetworking/Serialization, AFNetworking/Security, AFNetworking/Reachability, and more...] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping
>   code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in
>   target 'App')
> - ERROR | [AFNetworking/Serialization, AFNetworking/Security, AFNetworking/Reachability, and more...] xcodebuild: Returned an
>   unsuccessful exit code.
>
> Analyzed 1 podspec.
>
> [!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

any guys know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by running:

```
pod repo push MySpec AFNetworking.podspec --sources=MySpec,master --allow-warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Add AFNetworking pod name in your podspec file in dependency section.

s.dependency = 'AFNetworking, :path => ''